# How to get an array or list as result from a graphql query?

Tags: mongodb, graphql-js

Hello I am new to graphql and I was wondering if it is possible to create a root query in my schema that will return an array or list as a result.

To be more precise I have created the following type in my schema:

```
const ResourceType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name:'Resource',
  fields:()=>({
   id: {type: GraphQLID},
   url: {type: GraphQLString},
   title: {type: GraphQLString},
   author: {type: GraphQLString},
   license:{type: GraphQLString},
   LicenseScore: {type: GraphQLFloat},
 })
});
```

And I want to query all the resources in my database so that I get their license type and then assign a score according to the license. Is it possible to have a query that gets the license for each resource and returns an array like this: [[id:1209,score:3.5],[1203,4.5]....]?

I have created a mutation that updates the score to the database, here it is:

```
updateAllLicenses: {
     type: new GraphQLList(ResourceType),
     async resolve(parent,args){
     var licns;
     var scr;
     await Resource.find({}).then(async function(results){
       var num = results.length;
       var scr=0;
       for (var i=0; i<num; i++){
         if (! (results[i].license in licenseScores)){
           scr = 0;
         }
         else{
           scr = licenseScores[results[i].license];
         }
         await Resource.findByIdAndUpdate(results[i].id{LicenseScore:scr});
        }
      });
      return await Resource.find({});
    }
   }
```

However I was wondering if there is a way to get these scores directly from the query instead of saving them in the database. I tried changing the type to new GraphQLList(GraphQLFloat) and returning an array with the scr values but I get an error in the graphql api saying I have the wrong output type in my mutation.

Comment: Are you sure of the syntax of your wanted result: ` [[id:1209,score:3.5],[1203,4.5]....]?`? Or should you meant ` [[id:1209,score:3.5],[id:1203,score:4.5]....]?`

Comment: No I meant [[1209,3.5],[1203,4.5]] I only wrote the id and score to show the order in which I wish to save the values. Is it possible to get an array as a result from a query? if so what type should the return value have?

Answer (score -1):

From your schema, it seems to me that you are able to fetch results, as an array of objects, with an output like this:

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        license: "value1"
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        license: "value2"
    }
]
```

If this is all you need, then the **approximate** query should work:

```
query Resource {
    id
    url
    license
    licenseScore
}
```

Once you have your array of objects, you can convert it to an array of arrays, although I would not advise that.

Since you are just getting started in GraphQL, I recommened these resources:

- [HowToGraphql](https://www.howtographql.com/): clean videos/posts on GraphQL
- Apollo Graphql's documentation and blogs. Here is one of the posts on [queries](https://blog.apollographql.com/the-anatomy-of-a-graphql-query-6dffa9e9e747)

Also, if you want to test your queries and get accustomed to them, use [GraphQL Playground](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-playground)

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer and the links I will check them out. However that is what I am doing now in my code. What I was wondering is if I can remove the LicenseScore from the fields of the ResourceType in order to avoid the updating (it takes too long when I have many resources). Is there a way to return only an array of the scr values I calculate for each resource instead of an array of ResourceType objects?

Comment: I have some trouble understanding what you want to achieve. To my understanding now, you want to query your resource, and add computed fields (in this case licenseScore), in the response to your query. Is that right?

Comment: Then, you would have to simply define a new query, that get the results from the database, and before returning the response to the client, does modify the response by applying your logic related to the licenses and score. Same logic you put in your `updateAllLicenses`. Since you know how to create mutations, my guess is that you overlooked that you can create queries too, and that would be the right place to solve your requirement. At least, if my understanding is right of your situation.

Comment: Let me know if it works. I'll gladly take a look at the code if you want, just share it on github

Comment: Sorry, videos don't count as documentation.